# form object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: django, comments

I'm new to django. I have news app with view, which renders a page for each news:

```
def news_page(request, news_id):
    news = News.objects.get(pk=news_id)
    tags = news.tags.all()
    category = news.category
    comments = news.comment_set.all()
    form = add_comment(request, news.id)
    return render(request, 'news/news_page.html', {'form': form, 'news': news, 'tags': tags, 'category': category, 'user': request.user, 'comments': comments})
```

And I've created comment app:
models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment_body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    news = models.ForeignKey(News)
        pub_date = models.DateTineField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
```

forms.py:

```
class AddCommentForm(ModelForm):
    comment_body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta():
        model = Comment
        exclude = ('author', 'news','pub_date',)
```

I'l try realize comments.view function add_comment which news_page view (above) use:

```
def add_comment(request, news_id):
    news = News.objects.get(pk=news_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.news = news
            comment.save()
    else:
        form = AddCommentForm()
    return form
```

But I've got error 'AddCommentForm' object has no attribute 'has_header' . I think that's happen because add_comment view don't have HttpResponse. How should I rewrite code so that the idea become ​​working.
 Error traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /news/15/comment/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
, line 187, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middl
eware.py", line 26, in process_response
    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
  File "C:\Python27\myproject\djcode\first_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py", line
142, in patch_vary_headers
    if response.has_header('Vary'):
AttributeError: 'AddCommentForm' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

Thank's!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a view you need to return a `response` object , but you are returning the form object. Hence the error.

You can use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead

Change

```
return form
```

to

```
return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: What value should I replace template_name?

Comment: To the template you want to render the form on. If it is an ajax request, you can just do something like `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'form': form}))`

Comment: But this template (rendered in the first function) requires some other arguments. So if I write  return render(request, 'news/news_page.html', {'form': form}) it raise error NoReverseMatch at /news/15/comment/
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Is `/news/15/comment/` and ajax request ?

Comment: In that case, I would combine `news_page` and `addcomment` methods. That will make your life simpler

Comment: I thought about it...Thank's

Answer (score 0):

karthikr is right

You can also use

```
return render_to_response('template_name',{'form':form})
```